# Hyperlink in Splash Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, hyperlink

I can´t associate a hyperlink to the splash..
I'm trying to do this in my config.xml.
What i want is when you click on the splash, go to an external page.
How can i do that? Thank you!

My code:

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
<preference name="iosExtraFilesystems" value="library,library-nosync,documents,documents-nosync,cache,bundle,root" />
<preference name="AndroidExtraFilesystems" value="files,files-external,documents,sdcard,cache,cache-external,root" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="fade-splash-screen-duration" value="5" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/splashNew.png" width="320"  />
</platform>
<platform name="android">
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Internal" />
    <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/splashNew.png"  />
     <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
     <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" /> 
</platform>
```

Comment: You can't......